# JOptionPane before GUI in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

I'm trying to put a JOptionPane before my JFrame form in Netbeans I have tried putting it in the source of the Frame, it shows me the optionpane but when i click ok the frame doesnt appear just the mini,max,close buttons of the window show. I don't know where exactly I'm supposed to put the code for the optionpane for it to show before the frame. Can anyone help me out?

```
public final class CineVivero extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public void popups(){

    Object[] opening = {
        "Bienvenido a Movie Counter"
            + "\n Esta aplicación fue hecha para Multicines Metro Vivero."
            + "\n Aquí se podra registrar el porcentaje de ocupación de"
            + "\n las instalaciones y los ingresos desde el momento que se"
            + "\n abre la aplicación.",
    };

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, opening, "Movie Counter", 2);
}


public CineVivero() {
    popups();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            new CineVivero().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I should think that you would need to display your **JOptionPane** just before you execute the **JFrame.setVisible()** method.

Comment: Even if i move it into the main it still only shows me the popup

Comment: So, rather then relying on the constructor, display the `JOptionPane` separately, before you create the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but when i click ok the frame doesnt appear just the mini,max,close buttons of the window show

Have you added anything to frame? Have you specified it's size?  By default, the window is `0x0`

When I modify your code and set it's size (in this case `100x100`) it works fine for me

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public final class CineVivero extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public void popups() {

        Object[] opening = {
            "Bienvenido a Movie Counter"
            + "\n Esta aplicación fue hecha para Multicines Metro Vivero."
            + "\n Aquí se podra registrar el porcentaje de ocupación de"
            + "\n las instalaciones y los ingresos desde el momento que se"
            + "\n abre la aplicación.",};

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, opening, "Movie Counter", 2);
    }

    public CineVivero() {
        setSize(100, 100);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        popups();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                new CineVivero().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked! the only thing is that the frame isn't centered? even with setLocationRelativeTo(null);

Comment: @DanielaVillamizar It was centred on my screen

Comment: got it dumb mistake i had deleted the initComponents();                     why you always so mad programmer?

Comment: @DanielaVillamizar Using `setLocationRelativeTo` will display the window centred within context of "viewable" area, taking into considerations such things like the task bar or dock